# Will it block me if I ask another question?

Tags: support, post-ban

I have repeated a single question at several sites (Stack Overflow, Cross Validated, Data Science and Computer Science). I didn't know it would be an issue because they are different sites and I thought my question has something related to those fields. But when they complained they are duplicated and downvoted, I deleted those posts. I have a few questions that are not properly answered too. I have deleted some unanswered questions too.

My problem is, when I try to ask a new question, it shows following warning:

[image: Q block warning]

I would like to know whether it will really block my question if I ask any new question. (I am not a major in the programming field to answer the questions on Stack Overflow. For the moment, I have nothing to edit on those questions, and the answers for those questions are really not important for me too.)

Therefore, if I delete those questions will I be able to lift the warning?

Comment: It says you are in danger of being blocked if you carry on asking poorly received questions. Not that it is inevitable you will be blocked. Make sure that if you do ask another question it is a good one.

Comment: _"if I delete those questions will I be able to lift the warning?"_ Nope. Deleted questions still contribute to a possible question ban. Improve your questions by editing instead. Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th

Comment: What about modifying the already existing question to a new one? Ones that are not answered?

Answer (score 9):

Asking another question won't result in you getting banned.  Asking another *bad* question almost certainly *will* result in you getting banned.

You should spend some time reading through the help center, and the materials it references on how to ask appropriate questions, spend time looking at other questions to see what qualities are received well and what are received poorly, and spend considerable time crafting the next question you do decide to ask, to make absolutely sure that it's a *great* question that also conforms to the rules, guidelines, and conventions of the site.  If you don't, odds are good it'll be the last question you ask here.

Comment: While I get the last sentence in this context - it might be better to either remove it or slightly rephrase it :)

Comment: I agree it might not be nice @JonClements but given the fact that not many users are capable of getting out of a ban the stern wording might help to drive home the seriousness of the situation the OP is in. If the advice from Servy is taken lightheartedly the next meta post of the OP is about how to get out of the ban... no smileys here...

Comment: Why do we need to be soft @jon? Keep the last sentence. It might prevent one user from ending up question banned... Can we put that text in the warning dialog too?

Comment: It's advice he cannot refuse.